# Deleting All Temporary Files (ending with ~) in all subdirectories in bash

Tags: bash, file, delete-file, temporary

How would I delete all temporary files in a directory and its sub-directories (so it runs recursively) ?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
find . -name \*~ | xargs rm
```

I assume these are emacs temp files.  I deal with this all the time too.

Comment: with `-exec rm {} +` instead of `| xargs rm`, it won't break if files contain spaces, apostrophes and such.

Comment: yes exec rm is right, just experiment first with echo, I think you may need some escaping on the {}, but it has been a while ...